# Angular Controller or Service? What is cleaner

Tags: angularjs, rest, service, controller

I have a disagreement with my supervisor. We have a small Rest Application and i represent the opinion every controller has its own service. Additionally, there's a REST service like that:

`post(url, params = {}, options = {}) {
    return this.$http.post(url, params, options)
      .then(r => r.data);
}`

For validation I have a validation service that is called from the controller specific service.

My structure would look like this:
 
controller 
- loginController 
- boardController 

service 
- loginService 
- boardService 
- restService 
- validationService

My supervisor says that it's enough to put the logic from login-/boardService into login-/boardController because we would have redundant code and these services are unnecessary steps. I say that it's cleaner to split all up and have all rest logic in "x"Service which calls the restService and then, with the response, the validationService.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Your question title is very unclear.

Comment: hope it's better so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right...

Controller should be used to manipulate with view data, while service - for server communications.

It's not right to use server requests in controller.

Comment: His attempt is to call the restService from the "x"Controller which returns a validated object. My attempt is to have a own service for that what the controller would do. So the user can just inject the object from the "x"Service.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right. Btw, for a REST service consuming, there is a better suited libraries do exists. You should look at $resource (native angular way) or Restangular.